# Access EventTarget of addEventListener without using a variable

Tags: javascript

This codes removes the focus from the `select` element after you click it:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  select.blur();
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to change it so that it won't be necessary to assign a constant/variable first?

Something like this:

```js
// pseudocode
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  EventTarget.blur();
});
```

(And of course, I don't mean

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  document.querySelector('select').blur();
});
```

)

Comment: What is this meant to achieve? It makes your select element unusable.

Comment: Why you think this makes the select element useless? It works. Maybe you mean it makes select behave somewhat unusual? This is true, but I use this code for one of my userscripts, and not on a website. I'm not a web developer.

Comment: Why not just disable it?

Comment: Good question. This is an old script, maybe I have made some silly things there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. just modify your code a bit.

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  e.target.blur();
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `event.target` from function params

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  event.target.blur();
});
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```